# Fatal Error in SQL Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS running Lubuntu.

When trying to load a text into Learning With Texts language program i get a `Fatal Error in SQL Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE error`. The program works perfectly except this prevents the text from becoming loaded.

Tried to change the `my.cnf` files by enabling `local-infile`, etc. and that parameter is currently set to `on`.

```
Error Code & Message: [0]

Backtrace:

#0  do_mysqli_query(LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/tmpti.txt' INTO TABLE temptextitems FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@c) set TiSeID = @b, TiCount = (@d:=@d+CHAR_LENGTH(@c))+1-CHAR_LENGTH(@c), TiOrder = if(@c like "%\r",case when (@c:=REPLACE(@c,"\r","")) is NULL then NULL when (@b:=@b+1) is NULL then NULL when @d:= @e is NULL then NULL else @a:=@a+1 end, @a:=@a+1), TiText = @c,TiWordCount=('¶.!?:;' not like concat("%",@c,"%")) and (@c rlike '[\'a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ]+')) called at [/var/www/html/lwt/utilities.inc.php:3296]
```

I am expecting to be able to load a simple text into a table to be displayed on Learning With Texts, where i can then read in a foreign language. Everything on Learning with Texts works as expected except for the text being displayed. I instead get the above error message.

Even 'unsecure' solutions are fine as this is just a personal database which isn't important for anything so even if it got hacked or corrupted it wouldn't worry me.

Comment: After changing my.cnf you know you have to restart the server?

Comment: Hi yes i've restarted the server from terminal and restarted my actual laptop several times.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the server (mysql) as well as a setting in the client (php).

The client setting I needed to change to get this working was in the `php.ini` file. `phpinfo()` should show the current value. Uncommenting the following line in `php.ini` and then restarting the relevant web server / module (e.g. `php-fpm` in my case) worked:

`mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`